# Rails: Paperclip 4 - Renaming a file during creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have a Rails application with Paperclip 4 where there are products with images. Now, I want after an image is uploaded to rename the image to the product name.

e.g.

Product: `Really tasty sandwich`
Image: `really-tasty-sandwich-1.png`

The number at the end should be equal to the amount of images which the product possesses.

I tried interpolators but they don't really work for my case since I want the first image to be called `really-tasty-sandwich-1.png` and the second `really-tasty-sandwich-2.png` but interpolators changes both to `really-tasty-sandwich-2.png` since it is dynamically. The amount of images per product is available through `product.images.count` since it is a separate model.

So what I need is some logic which renames the image so a user can upload an image with whatever name he wants and it will be renamed correctly.

Does somebody have an idea how it works? Probably something with callbacks I guess.

Thanks

Edit:

My image model logic so far:

```
has_attached_file :image,
                path: ':rails_root/public/product_images/:attachment/:id_partition/:normalized_filename',
                url: '/product_images/:attachment/:id_partition/:normalized_filename'

Paperclip.interpolates :normalized_filename do |attachment, style|
  if attachment.instance.product.present?
    attachment.instance.normalized_filename(attachment.content_type)
  else
    attachment.original_filename
  end
end

def normalized_filename(content_type)
  "#{product.name.downcase.split(' ').join('-')}-#{product.images.count}.#{content_type.split('/').last}"
end
```

Comment: Please post what you have so far. At least the interpolators you've used to attempt the name change.

Comment: Sure! I updated my question

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just updating the `_file_name` column using your `normalized_filename` method as opposed to generating it dynamically?

Comment: This would ne an after create callback for instance?

Comment: Then I would have to change the filename on disk as well I presume

Comment: Yes, exactly right.